# As of January 2015, are Phukets beaches that have been "cleaned up" by the government still clean?

Tags: thailand, beaches, phuket

There were [news in July 2014](http://www.travelfish.org/blogs/thailand/2014/07/22/phuket-coup-beach-cleanup-part-two/) about the government having cleaned up the beaces of Phuket from vendors, restaurants and sun chairs.

Are these changes permanent until today? Or have the businesses come back to life?

Answer (score 3):

Beaches are still free of the vendors and chairs.  The current government is not easily ignored.

Comment: Can I ask when have you seen that?

Comment: I am currently driving back from southern Thailand after two weeks of cycling down the coast in Khao Lak, Phuket, Krabi.  We didn't hit every beach, but those we did are still empty.